# How to make lights flash like in stranger things

Tags: video, lighting

So i have this scene where there's a lot of on tube lights and i wanna dim some of them and turn them back on (replicating the flashing effect in stranger things) so does anyone have an app that can do that? Do make sure to tell me how to do it in said app please.

Comment: Can you find a clip of what you are talking about, and add it into your question. If you can, also add a clip of your footage.  When you say tube, do you mean fluorescent lights? Or tube like a metro station? Also add what platform you're working on, what software you have access too, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of thing they use these days -

[image]

It looks like a 'neon' or fluorescent tube, but it's actually LED driven. They can be remotely controlled or programmed into virtually any pattern, any colour. They drive from a phone/pad app or over DMX.

In the old days, they'd have to use actual fluorescent tubes, individually switched, some with intentionally bad starters to make them flicker. They were horrible to work with because they weren't really very controllable, so it's LED all the way now.

Downside: They're damned expensive - $£€ 650 each - but you can rent them.
Example - https://astera-led.com/products/titan/
& watch the video to really see what they can do -